# backbone collection change doesn't get triggered when changing model

Tags: backbone.js

I'm building a frontend with backbone on top of an API and wonder, why the `change` event doesn't get triggered. Fetching and saving works, but the template doesn't get rerendered.

**Collection**

```
var Clients = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: API.host + '/clients',
  model: Client
});
```

**Model**

```
var Client = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: API.host + '/clients',
  defaults: {
    clients: {
      number: '',
      company: '',
      address1: '',
      address2: '',
      city: '',
      zip: '',
      country: '',
      tax: '',
      email: '',
      phone: ''
    }
  }
});
```

**View**

```
var ClientsView = Backbone.View.extend({

  id: 'content',

  initialize: function() {

    // instantiate Collection
    this.model = new Clients();

    // compile Handlebars template
    this.tpl = Handlebars.compile(this.template);

    // bind change and reset model events to rerender template
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    this.model.bind('reset', this.render);
  },

  render: function() {

    var self = this;
    var obj = this.el;

    // get clients and set data to handlebars template
    $.when(this.model.fetch()).then(function(response) {
      $(obj).html(self.tpl(response));
    }, function() {
      $(obj).html(self.tpl);
    });

    return this;
  },

  events: {
    "click #client-save": "save"
  },

  save: function(e) {

    // cache target and parent object for quick form access
    var obj = e.target;
    var parent = $(obj).closest('#client-modal');

    var client = new Client({
      clients: {
        number: parent.find('[name="number"]').val(),
        company: parent.find('[name="company"]').val(),
        address1: parent.find('[name="address1"]').val(),
        address2: parent.find('[name="address2"]').val(),
        city: parent.find('[name="city"]').val(),
        zip: parent.find('[name="zip"]').val(),
        country: parent.find('[name="country"]').val(),
        tax: parent.find('[name="tax"]').val(),
        email: parent.find('[name="email"]').val(),
        phone: parent.find('[name="phone"]').val(),
        web: parent.find('[name="web"]').val()
      }
    });

    client.save();

    return false;

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass the context when you bind your functions.

this.model.bind('change', this.render, **this**)

Try to use another name for your collection instance.

```
// Example
this.collectionClients = new Clients();
```

\0/

Comment: `this.model.bind('change', this.render, this)` did the trick! :) But why should I use another name for my collection instance?

Comment: When you create a variable called model inside your view, backbone for convention will assumes that you have a model attached in your view And that's not your cenario.

Comment: `this.collection` would be the usual name for a collection property in your view, that even has the same special handling that `this.model` does. [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) is usually a better way to hook up events than `bind`.